# Somar a coluna(tabela matriculado) valor total e atribuir o valor ao um label e se for desmarcado atualizar o valor

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Cadastrar Compra Fornecedor</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilo.css">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- jQuery (necessario para os plugins Javascript Bootstrap) -->
        <script src="../bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../bootstrap/js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/mascara.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/botaoBusca.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="../bootstrap/js/jquery.maskMoney.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tabela.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background: #e1f2d0;">

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function byID(el) {
                return document.getElementById(el);
            }

// Calcula a quantidade x total
            function total(un, qnt) {
                $(document).on('keyup', 'input[name="qnt[]"]', function () {
                    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var qtde = tr.find('input[name="qnt[]"]').val();


                    qnt = qtde;

                    var vlrunt = tr.find('input[name="valor_unitario[]"]').val();

                    un = vlrunt;

                    var total1 = (qnt.length && qnt >= 0) ? parseFloat(un.replace(",", "."), 10) * parseFloat(qnt.replace(",", "."), 10) : 0;


                    tr.find('input[name="total[]"]').val(total1);
                    // Fix para campos vazios
                    // return (qnt.length && qnt >= 0) ? parseFloat(un.replace(",", "."), 10) * parseFloat(qnt.replace(",", "."), 10) : 0;
                });
            }

// Função que formata o dinheiro
            function formatMoney(v) {
                if (v.indexOf(".") === -1) {
                    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");
                }
                v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, "$1,$20");
                v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, "$1,$2");
                v = v.replace(/([\d]+)([\d]{3}),([\d]{2})$/, "$1.$2,$3");
                return v;
            }

// Calcula o total toral
            function calculaoTotalTotal() {
                var total_total = 0, id = 1;
                // Corre todos os campos infinatamente
                for (; ; ) {
                    var campo = byID("total" + id); // Pega a quantidade
                    // Para o for quando não acha campos 
                    if (campo == undefined) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        // Vertifica se o campo esta preenchido e calcula
                        if (campo.value.length) {
                            total_total += parseFloat(campo.value.replace(",", "."), 10);
                        }
                    }
                    id++;
                }
                byID("somaTotal").innerHTML = formatMoney(total_total.toString()); // Formata e Imprime Total Total
            }

// Recebe a ação de quantidade do input
            function calcTotal(id) {
                var id = id.replace("qnt", ""); // Traz apenas o número de ID
                var valor_unitario = byID("valor_unitario" + id).value; // Pega o valor unitario daquele bloco de ID
                var quantidade = byID("qnt" + id).value; // Pega a quantidade
                var soma = total(valor_unitario, quantidade); // Realiza a soma da quantidade x preço
                byID("total" + id).value = formatMoney(soma.toString()); // Formata e Imprime no Total
                calculaoTotalTotal(); // Calcula todos os campos
            }

       </script>



        <div class="container" style="background-color: white; padding: 0%;border-right: 1px solid #00913d; border-left: 1px solid #00913d;">
            <img src="../imagem/coo.jpg" style="height: 30%; width:100%"/>
            <div style="background-color: #009042;margin-top: 0em;color: white;text-align: right;height: 4em;font-weight: bold;padding-top: 1em">
                <?php
                session_start();
                echo "Bem-vindo, " . $_SESSION["nome"] . "<a id='sair' href ='../index.php'> (SAIR)</a> ";
                ?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <?php
                require_once '../MenuAdmin.php';
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="jumbotron" style="background: white;">
                <h4 id="h1" style="margin-left: 30%;font-weight: bold">Registrar Compra do Fornecedor</h4>

                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" >
                    <div style="background-color:#aad3ac" class="panel-heading"> <strong class="">Dados da Compra</strong>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label style="text-align: left" id="data" for="data" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Data*:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <input style=" margin-left: 0%" type="date" required="true" class="form-control" name="data" id="data">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label style="text-align: left" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Fornecedor*:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <?php
                                        require_once '../controle/Controle.php';
                                        require_once '../controle/ControleFornecedor.php';

                                        $obj = new ControleFornecedor();
                                        $lista = $obj->listaFornecedorT();
                                        ?>

                                        <select class="form-control" id="fornecedor" name="fornecedor">
                                            <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Selecione..</option>
                                            <?php
                                            for ($i = 0; $i < count($lista); $i++) {
                                                ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $lista[$i]['idcodigo']; ?>">
                                                    <?php echo $lista[$i]['empresa']; ?>
                                                </option>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="background-color:#aad3ac;" class="panel-heading"> <strong class="">INSUMO ADICIONADOS</strong>
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <b>Total Total:</b> <div id="somaTotal"></div>   


                                    <!--<label id="totalCampra" style="margin-left: 50%;color: red" >TOTAL:</label>-->
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                echo "<table id='matriculado'>";
                                echo "<thead>";
                                echo "<th>-</th>";
                                echo "<th>Descricao</th>";
                                echo "<th>UN</th>";
                                echo "<th>Quantidade</th>";
                                echo "<th>Valor Unitario</th>";
                                echo "<th class='total'>Valor total</th>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                                echo "</thead>";
                                echo "<tbody>";
                                echo "</tbody>";
                                echo "</table>";
                                ?>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <div style="background-color:#aad3ac;" class="panel-heading"> <strong class="">Selecione os Insumos:</strong>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                require_once '../controle/FuncoesControle.php';
                                require_once '../classe/Insumo.php';
                                require_once '../controle/ControleInsumo.php';

                                $con2 = conectar_banco();
                                $cm2 = "select * from insumo ";
                                $rs2 = pg_query($cm2);
                                $lista2 = pg_fetch_all($rs2);

                                //$valor = $lista2[0]['valorunitario'];


                                if ($rs2) {
                                    //6 - verificando se a consulta retornou algum reg.
                                    if (pg_num_rows($rs2) > 0) { //se retornou pelo menos 1 reg.
                                        // 7 - exibir resultados
                                        $lista2 = pg_fetch_all($rs2);
                                        echo "<form method='POST'>";
                                        echo "<div class='container'>";
                                        echo "<hr>";
                                        echo "<div class='row'>";
                                        echo "<div class='panel panel-primary filterable'>";
                                        echo "<div class='panel-heading'>";
                                        echo " <div class='pull-right'>";
                                        echo "</div>";
                                        echo "</div>";

                                        echo "<table class='resultados, table' id='disponiveis'>";
                                        echo " <thead>";
                                        echo"<tr class='filters'>" .
                                        "<th>-</th>" .
                                        "<th><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Descricao'></th>" .
                                        "<th>Un</th>" .
                                        "<th>Quantidade</th>" .
                                        "<th>Valor Un</th>" .
                                        "<th>Valor total</th>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                        echo "</thead>";
                                        echo "<tbody>";
                                        foreach ($lista2 as $key => $value) {
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                            $codigo = $value['idcodigo'];
                                            $valor = $value['valorunitario'];
                                            $rec1 = substr($valor, 3);
                                            $rec1 = str_replace(".", "", $rec1);
                                            $rec1 = str_replace(',', '.', $rec1);
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<td class='direita'><input type='checkbox' name='adicionar'/></td>";
                                            // echo "<td><input type='radio' class='seleciona' value='$codigo' name='seleciona' id='enable'/></td>";
                                            echo "<td class='name'> {$value['descricao']} </td>";
                                            echo "<td> {$value['unidade']} </td>";
                                            echo "<td> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='qnt[]' id='qnt' onkeyup='calcTotal(this.id)'> </td>";
                                            //echo "<div id='{$value['idcodigo']}' onclick='alert( this.id )'> janela </div>"; 
                                            echo "<td> <input type='text' class='form-control' value='$rec1' name='valor_unitario[]' id='valor_unitario' readonly='readonly' /> </td>";
                                            echo "<td> <input type='text' name='total[]' id='total' readonly='readonly' class='total' style='color: red'/> </td>";
                                            //echo "<td> <button type='button' class='salvar' id='$codigo' name='salvar' style='background-color:#009042;border-color: #009042;color:white'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign'></i></button></td>";
                                            //echo "<td><a href='GerenciarCooperado.php?acao=excluir&idpessoa={$value['idpessoa']}'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' id='excluir'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></button></a></td>";
                                            echo "</tr>\n";
//                    echo "</tr>\n";
                                        }
                                        echo"</tbody>";
                                        echo "</table>";
                                        echo "</div>";

                                        echo "</form>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "A consulta não retornou resultados";
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    echo "erro ao executar consulta";
                                }
                                ?>



                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div id="aviso" class="alert alert-info" style="font-size:100%;font-weight: bold; text-align: center">
                                        Atenção! Os campos com asterisco(*) é obrigatório.
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 
                                <div class ="form-group last">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                                        <button style="background-color:#009042; margin-top: 0%" type="submit" name="salvar" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                                            Salvar
                                        </button>
                                        <a href="../gerenciar/GerenciarAplicacao.php"><button style="background-color:red; margin-top: 0%; margin-left: 0%;" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color:#009042;border-color: #009042"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Cancelar</button></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        </form>

                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img id="rodape" src="../imagem/rodape2.jpg" style="height: 10%; width:100%; margin-bottom: 0%" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //consultando todos os input to type checkbox na pagina
        //caso a sua pagina possua mais inputs deste tipo, você deve tornar o filtro abaixo mais especifico.
        var adicionar = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
        //consultando as tabelas que irão armazenar as disciplinas disponiveis e as que o aluno está matriculado.
        var matriculado = document.querySelector("#matriculado tbody");
        var disponiveis = document.querySelector("#disponiveis tbody");
        //definindo o evento que irá mover a linha, é importante instanciar apenas um evento para todos os checkbox.
        var adicionarOnClick = function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var qtde = tr.find('input[name="qnt[]"]').val();
            if (qtde == "") {
                alert("Digite a quantidade");
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            } else {

                //caso o checkbox esteja marcado, mova a linha para a tabela de matriculados, caso contrario para a tabela de disciplinas disponiveis.
                var escopo = this.checked ? matriculado : disponiveis;
                //this é o checkbox que foi clickado, o parentNode dele é a celula atual, e o parentNode da celula é a linha (arvore).
                escopo.appendChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);

                var total_total = 0, id = 1;
                // Corre todos os campos infinatamente
                for (; ; ) {
                    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var campo = tr.find('input[name="qnt[]"]').val();
                    alert("campo" + campo);

                    // Para o for quando não acha campos 
                    if (campo < 0) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        alert("Entrou1");
                        // Vertifica se o campo esta preenchido e calcula
//                        if (campo.value.length) {
                            alert("Entrou");
                            var tr1 = $(this).closest('tr');
                            var total_total = tr1.find('input[name="total[]"]').val();
                            alert("total" + total_total);
                            total_total += parseFloat(campo.value.replace(",", "."), 10);

//                        }
                    }
                    id++;
                }
                byID("somaTotal").innerHTML = total_total; // Formata e Imprime Total Tota
            }
        };
        //registrando o evento criado acima para todos os checkbox.
        for (var indice in adicionar) {
            adicionar[indice].onclick = adicionarOnClick;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Eu tenho a tabela "Produtos" e quando selecionada ela passa a linha para a de itens inclusos. O problema é que não estou conseguindo atribuir o valor do total para um label. Gostaria de quando o cara selecionar e ir para a tabela de itens adicionados fosse somando no valor total da compra e quando fosse descamado a opção voltar subtrair do valor.